# Are TestMethods inside a TestClass executed in parallel?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a `TestClass` containing a member variable (the class that is being tested) that is initialized in a setup method with the `[Testinitialize]` attrib. Now i have multiple tests for this member in different methods marked with `[TestMethod]` attrib.

Each method modifies the member object slightly to test various scenarios.

My question is do the test methods inside a test class ever get executed in parallel?

If they do run in parallel (by parallel i mean in separate threads) depending on the runner - having a single object in the test class wouldn't be correct ? The state of the object could be changed in either `[TestMethod]` and end up in a bad state?

Comment: Depends on your test runner, which one are you using? the one built in to visual studio or some other 3rd party runner?

Comment: I am currently running it on visual studio. It would eventually be part of a cloud based solution to gate any pull request to my master branch. Updated the question with some questions

Comment: Tests should be independent, you should write them _as if_ they ran in parallel.

Comment: _each method modifies the member object slightly ..._ - so how do you control that now? Do (all) the tests have to run in a particular sequence?

Comment: each test method tests out a different scenario. which is achieved by setting a parameter to a different value.

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - no the tests don't have to run in any sequence - its just that they are re-using a single object. It seems l should just create one object per test - instead of re-using the same.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently *Visual Studio 2015* now supports parallel unit testing, I have not tried it so I honestly do not understand the implications of that.

`TestInitialize` is called for each Test, there is a `ClassInitialize` attribute that will be called once for the entire Test Class regardless of which Tests are scheduled to be executed.

Comment: Awesome.  +1 for you.  Wishing you well ;)